# Dealing with React Child from Mapped Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have rows in a table which I have a button rendered from an array. (I'll exclude the full row for brevity)

```
  onDeleteAttachment = async (event, file) => {
    try {
        await this.props.deleteAttachment(file.Url);
        //Success now remove the row from the table
        var qualification = this.state.currentQualification;
        qualification._Attachments = qualification._Attachments.filter(a=> a != file);
        this.setState({currentQualification: qualification});
    }
    catch(ex){
        //Failed, I need to turn off the loader on the button
    }
  }


  render{
   return myArray.map(button => <DeleteButton onClick={onDeleteAttachment}>click me</DeleteButton>)
  }
```

When the button is clicked it shows a loader. The `DeleteButton` is rendered like so:

```
   onClick(event){
      this.setState({loading: ture}); //This makes button turn into loader
       this.props.onClick(event); //push onchange to parent
   }

   render(){
       return 
    <Button onClick={onClick}>{this.state.loading ? "Loading" : "click me" </button>
   }
```

the problem I have, is I have no way of telling the child `DeleteButton` to turn off the loader?

Answer (score 0):

Remove try-catch and let `onDeleteAttachment` throw the error (or re-throw the error after you've caught and processed it):

```
onDeleteAttachment = async (event, file) => {
    await this.props.deleteAttachment(file.Url);
    //Success now remove the row from the table
    var qualification = this.state.currentQualification;
    qualification._Attachments = qualification._Attachments.filter(a=> a != file);
    this.setState({currentQualification: qualification});
}
```

And add try-catch to the `DeleteButton`'s `onClick` method so it can catch the unhandled exception and manage its own state.

```
 onClick(event){
     try {
         this.setState({loading: true}); //This makes button turn into loader
         this.props.onClick(event); //push onchange to parent
     }
     catch(ex) {
         this.setState({loading: false}); // Failed to delete, turn loader off
     }
 }
```